# How to understand partitioning and distribution in sparksql?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I can't figure out what's the difference between `partitioning` and `distribution` defined in `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.physical.partitioning.scala`, can somebody show me some examples to explain their difference? Thanks!